# Wildfly ClassNotFoundException when using new module dependency

Tags: jboss, wildfly, log4j2

Wildfly logs are blowing up on startup with several ClassNotFoundException's after adding a new module for Log4j2. It kind of seems like it's looking in that module for other Java EE classes that my newly defined module has nothing to do with.

Here is one of the Exceptions:

```
    17:52:57,865 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) Failed to define class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.AbstractJMSReceiver in Module "org.apache.log4j2:main" from local module loader @1c323a (finder: local module finder @125871f (roots: /usr/local/share/wildfly/modules,/usr/local/share/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/logging/log4j/core/net/AbstractJMSReceiver (Module "org.apache.log4j2:main" from local module loader @1c323a (finder: local module finder @125871f (roots: /usr/local/share/wildfly/modules,/usr/local/share/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base)))
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.ResolverUtil.addIfMatching(ResolverUtil.java:436) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.ResolverUtil.loadImplementationsInJar(ResolverUtil.java:411) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.ResolverUtil.loadImplementationsInJar(ResolverUtil.java:367) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.ResolverUtil.findInPackage(ResolverUtil.java:264) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:174) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:130) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.BaseConfiguration.start(BaseConfiguration.java:152) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:341) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:386) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:149) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:84) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:35) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:444) [log4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:389) [log4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at com.extraliga.domain.ExtraligaEntity.<init>(Unknown Source) [extraliga-persistence.jar:]
        at com.extraliga.domain.util.EmailConverter.<init>(Unknown Source) [extraliga-persistence.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.XMLContext.setLocalAttributeConverterDefinitions(XMLContext.java:206) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.XMLContext.addDocument(XMLContext.java:113) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:528) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:517) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:512) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:686) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:724) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildHibernateConfiguration(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1163) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:846) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474) [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.MessageListener from [Module "org.apache.log4j2:main" from local module loader @1c323a (finder: local module finder @125871f (roots: /usr/local/share/wildfly/modules,/usr/local/share/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base))]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        ... 67 more
```

At the moment I am just trying to deploy my persistence unit archive to make sure I've mapped everything correctly, and this archive depends on Log4j2. In the META-INF directory of my persistence archive I have a jboss-deployment-structure.xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j2">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

My module is defined by the following directory structure in Wildfly:

```
$WILDFLY_HOME/modules/org/apache/log4j2/main/
    log4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar
    log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar
    module.xml
```

And finally my module.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.log4j2">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="log4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.lmax.disruptor"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

It seems very odd that wildfly would even be trying to look for javax.jms.MessageListener at this point, and even more so that it is looking for it "from org.apache.log4j2:main"

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WildFly isn't trying to look for `javax.jms.MessageListener` the `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.AbstractJMSReceiver` is. I don't know how many other dependencies log4j2 has, but you'll at least need to add `javax.jmx` as a dependency.

Comment: The dependency tree (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/dependencies.html#Dependency_Tree ) mentions org.jboss.spec.javax.jms:jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final

Comment: That did it, turns out the module needs several libraries including two new modules from third parties. There's probably an easier way to do this, but it's working for now. Thank you.

Comment: also, that javax.servlet.api dependency looks completely unneeded.